# Using your NSURLResponse(webViewHack)

Tags: uiwebview

I now went to put [this code check SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476539/uiwebview-capturing-the-response-headers/15477801#15477801) into another app and I am getting an error on the line:

```
if ((self = originalImp(self, _cmd, cf))) {
```

The build error is:

> "Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3"

I am using *Xcode 6.2 compiling for iOS 7.1*

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

You can Disable the check in the Project Build Settings by setting 'Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend Calls' to No.
Has worked for me in similar situations. Filter the Build Settings on the keyword 'strict' to find it easily.

Comment: Thanks very much Arius. Appreciated.