# Get HTTP Response header on UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, swift, http, uiwebview

How can I get HTTP headers response from WebView? I've found semi-solutions [at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15476975/4532985), but it's written on Objective-C and can't convert it to Swift (I've tried with my poor Obj-C knowledge).

Objective-C code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSCachedURLResponse *resp = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
    NSLog(@"%@",[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)resp.response allHeaderFields]);
}
```

1. How that code will look at Swift?
2. Maybe now we have better ways to do so? Caching is not always enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift**

Swift is more stringent ; you want to protect yourself against `nil` pointers and `optionals`:

- check that the `webView` actually has a `request`
- check that the `request` actually has a `NSCachedURLResponse`
- type-check the response against `NSHTTPURLResponse`

```swift
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    if let request = webView.request {
        if let resp = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request) {
            if let response = resp.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print(response.allHeaderFields)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cachedResponseForRequest` always returning nil, workaround? or am I missing to implement something?

Comment: ditto. cachedResponseForRequest returning nil. Apple forums mention a bug. Workaround?

Comment: Has anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: Same result, nil for `if let resp = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request) {`

Answer (score 0):

Just using this in **SWIFT 3.1** :

```
if let request = webView.request {
            if let resp = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request) {
                if let response = resp.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print(response.allHeaderFields)
                }
            }
        }
```