# How can I get the HTTP status field from a WebView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

How can I get the HTTP status field from a WebView in Swift 2?

I tried this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let status = webView.request?.valueForHTTPHeaderField("Status")
    print("Status: \(status)")
}
```

But `status` remains `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log all the fields you can get from this http response.
Here is a link that might be usefull : [Get HTTP Response header on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880416/get-http-response-header-on-uiwebview)

Comment: There is no tag like 'status' available or anything simular. But thanks anyway for the information.